# Encryption using switch statement

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

I'm doing an encryption program, my professor told me that this program is correct, but my logic in the `switch` statement is wrong, because of inputting the encryption value one by one.. my professor wants me to put it in a variable first then display it on the encryption value .. please help me out ..

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<windows.h>
#include<cstdlib>

main()
{
const char *stringlength;
char input[100];
int i;

cout<<"Input letters only:";
cin>>input;
stringlength=input;
cout<<"\nEncryption Value:";
for(i=0; i<strlen(stringlength); i++)
{

    switch(input[i])
    {
    case 'a':cout<<"0";break;
    case 'A':cout<<"1";break;
    case 'e':cout<<"2";break;
    case 'E':cout<<"3";break;
    case 'i':cout<<"4";break;
    case 'I':cout<<"5";break;
    case 'o':cout<<"6";break;
    case 'O':cout<<"7";break;
    case 'u':cout<<"8";break;
    case 'U':cout<<"9";break;
    case 'B':cout<<"C";break;
    case 'C':cout<<"D";break;
    case 'D':cout<<"E";break;
    case 'F':cout<<"G";break;
    case 'G':cout<<"H";break;
    case 'H':cout<<"I";break;
    case 'J':cout<<"K";break;
    case 'K':cout<<"L";break;
    case 'L':cout<<"M";break;
    case 'M':cout<<"N";break;
    case 'N':cout<<"O";break;
    case 'P':cout<<"Q";break;
    case 'Q':cout<<"R";break;
    case 'R':cout<<"S";break;
    case 'S':cout<<"T";break;
    case 'T':cout<<"U";break;
    case 'V':cout<<"W";break;
    case 'W':cout<<"X";break;
    case 'X':cout<<"Y";break;
    case 'Y':cout<<"Z";break;
    case 'Z':cout<<"A";break;
    case 'b':cout<<"c";break;
    case 'c':cout<<"d";break;
    case 'd':cout<<"e";break;
    case 'f':cout<<"g";break;
    case 'g':cout<<"h";break;
    case 'h':cout<<"i";break;
    case 'j':cout<<"k";break;
    case 'k':cout<<"l";break;
    case 'l':cout<<"m";break;
    case 'm':cout<<"n";break;
    case 'n':cout<<"o";break;
    case 'p':cout<<"q";break;
    case 'q':cout<<"r";break;
    case 'r':cout<<"s";break;
    case 's':cout<<"t";break;
    case 't':cout<<"u";break;
    case 'v':cout<<"w";break;
    case 'w':cout<<"x";break;
    case 'x':cout<<"y";break;
    case 'y':cout<<"z";break;
    case 'z':cout<<"a";break;
    default : cout<<"\nInvalid Character!\n"; break;
    }
}
getch();
return 0;
}
```

What can I do with that? my hint is that I need a variable where I can put all the encryption value of the text, then `cout` it all at once.

Comment: Never thought I'd see turboc++ and c++11 in the same tag list.

Comment: Do you know how to iterate over an array? Do you know how to put values into an array? What's the problem?

Comment: Just that you notify, in c++ you won't get that fast in trouble as in c, but you are just allowed to place 16384 `case` labels into a switch statement. (In C the implemantation limit for it is set to 1023)

Comment: Not meaning to demoralize you too much, but this is an ultra-poor implementation of an ultra-poor encryption scheme. Unless the assignment is "learn to use the `switch` statement", you should consider using an array to look up the substituted characters. Way less complexity, much easier to read and modify (as in "change key"), and faster.

Comment: What happens if I have a sticky key on my keyboard, and input 1000 `'a'`?  (Moral: _don't_ use `char[]` for this, but `std::string`.  Even if I have a file with 2GB of `'a'`, it will blow up in a controlled way.)

Comment: i'm really a beginner, my prof didnt teach us .. :( he teaches us only basics like this..

Comment: and to say that this is the first time i encounter programming subjects even if my course is not in programming line,, i just need this to pass my subject thats all..

Comment: @Damon: It's actually not _that_ poor. Call it an S-Box, and it's suddenly just incomplete. It's missing a P-box (shuffle) and a loop to perform a few more iterations. Still not NSA-proof, of course, and having the key hardcoded is rather inconvenient.

Comment: @MSalters: That's a very positive way of looking at it :-) What I was trying to say is that a simple substitution cipher is hardly your-litte-sister proof, no need for the NSA. Even with a more complicated mapping (and without source code), it suffers from being trivially reversible by mapping character counts to symbols, as you have probably read in "The Adventure of the Dancing Men" when you were 6 years old.

Answer (score 1):

Use a C++ std::string as you output and add every cypherred character to it. Instead of cout << 'c' use str += 'c'; Then just dump the whole string.

Answer (score 1):

Use string streams in C++.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
```

Put this in your main function declarations:

```
std::stringstream ss;
```

Following in switch case:

```
case 'a':ss<<"0";break;
case 'A':ss<<"1";break;
case 'e':ss<<"2";break;
case 'E':ss<<"3";break;
case 'i':ss<<"4";break;
case 'I':ss<<"5";break;
case 'o':ss<<"6";break;
...
```

Finally read stream into the string output and print -

```
std::string output = ss.str(); 
cout << output << "\n";
```

Comment: I modified your code to be a bit ... better. I hope you don't mind. Your version would have broken on a space in `ss`.

Comment: That's really abuse of `std::stringstream` (which should be `std::ostringstream` here anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Your prof is probably looking for `char output[100]`. That's about as bad as `char input[100]`, for the reasons that James Kanze explained, but your professor seems stuck in the previous century. This kind of code is what causes hackers.